# Selenium/Python functional test: find sibling element according to link text

Tags: python, selenium, css-selectors

I am running functional tests with Selenium and Python. In the test I ultimately want to check the text of a `p` tag with a `hash-tag` class. The contents of this `p` tag is dependent on an `a` tag's text which is a child element of a `h3` which is a sibling element of the `p` tag with a `hash-tag` class.

So for example (see the markup below) if the `a` tag's text is 'Paramount’s Pop Culture Staying Power' then I want to:

- get the `h3` parent of that `a` tag
- get the first sibling of that `h3` tag that is a `p` tag with a `hash-tag` class
- check if that `p` tag's text is '#IMDB'
- get the next `p` tag with a `hash-tag` class
- check if that `p` tag's text is '#Paramount'

[image]

So far I'm only able to grab the `a` tag by it's text but I'm not sure how to traverse to the p tags with a `hash-tag` class:

```
def setUpClass(cls):
    cls.browser = webdriver.Chrome()

def test_DB_tags(self):
    paramount_link = self.browser.find_element_by_link_text('Paramount’s Pop Culture Staying Power')
```

Comment: Paste this html code into the question. How are people supposed to test it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`link_text` is for anchor tag that is `a` tag in HTML.

1. `h3` parent of that `a` tag

   `//a[text()='your string']/..`

`/..` represent go to parent tag from current node.

2. get the first sibling of that `h3` tag that is a `p` tag with a `hash-tag class`

   `//a[text()='your string']/../following-sibling::p[@class='lead db-explanation']`
3. check if that `p` tag's text is `'#IMDB'`

`//a[text()='your string']/../following-sibling::p[text()='#IMDb']`

4. get the next `p` tag with `a` `hash-tag class`

This is same like 2nd Point, and you can write for 5th as well. Do try to write by yourself and let me know I can verify it.

Read more about xpath axes [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are looking for clear, you can do the following:

1. From the `a` tag element get it's text.

```
sentence = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@href]').text
```

2. Get the first word from the sentence

```
first_word = sentence.split(' ', 1)[0]
```

Now, to locate the first element you are looking for with `p` tag and `hash-tag` class and get it's text can be done as following:

```
first_p_text = driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//a[@href]/../..//p[@class="hash-tag"])[1]').text
```

And the second `p` there text will be

```
second_p_text = driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//a[@href]/../..//p[@class="hash-tag"])[2]').text
```

Now the assertions:

```
self.assertTrue(first_p_text in first_word)
self.assertTrue(second_p_text in "#IMDB")
```